# Do all tasks need to be inspected for process children?

Tags: linux, procfs

On Linux, I want to find all child processes for a given process. I cannot rely on tools like pstree; I need to make use of procfs only.

[Since 2012](https://lwn.net/Articles/475688/), it has been possible to look up child processes from /prod/PID/task/XXX/children.

Many processes have a single task, but some have a very high number of tasks. It seems there's always a task where task ID is equal to process ID, let's call it the *special task*, unless someone knows of a better name for it.

If I want to find all child processes for a process with process ID *p*, **do I need to iterate over all tasks, or it it enough to inspect the *special task***?

(If it's enough to inspect one task, then I'd like to save syscalls and time by not having to iterate over all tasks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation states that tid/children is only reliable when everything is stopped, and if not, you are better of traversing all pids. I do not follow why not use pstree, it uses procfs. See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html .

The 'xxx' part is just thread id. The "special task" is called a "thread group leader" or just the main thread or starting thread.

Yes, you have to iterate over all threads to get all process childs.

Comment: About "Yes, you have to iterate over all threads to get all process childs": I believe you, but do you happen to have a link to some kind of authoritative documentation which also states it?

Comment: `do you happen to have a link to some kind of authoritative documentation which also states it?` No. I inferred this from the code comments from the diff you posted link to.